# implicit cast or normal cast when dividing 2 ints?

Tags: java, casting, int

Is there any difference in performance between doing an int division with a cast or implicit cast

eg.

```
         int a = 7;
         int b = 3;


      float x = ((float)a)/b;

      or

      float y = (a+0f)/b;
```

Answer (score 3):

As the comments point out, the two versions are different because of operator precedence rules.

```
float y = a + 0f / b;
```

is actually equivalent to

```
 float y = a + (0f / b);
```

i.e.

```
 float y = a;
```

You should have written

```
 float y = (a + 0f) / b;
```

Provided that you get the operator precedence correct, there is no difference, semantically, or in terms of performance.  (The JIT compiler is highly likely to optimize away the artificial addition of zero.)

However, there is an important difference.  Your second form is an *unusual* idiom, and unusual idioms make it harder for other people to read your code.  It is best to write your code the "normal" way ... if you (or your boss!!) anticipate that other people may need to read / maintain it.

(And if you make a habit of getting the operator precedence wrong, they may need to read your code sooner than you expect ... :-) )